# Bosch Nyon range estimates are unreliable

Tags: electric-bike

I have a [Bosch Nyon computer](http://www.bosch-ebike.de/en/komponenten/nyon/nyon.php) and after charging the battery I very often get a range (in eco) of +/- 230, 220 km which is adjusted downwards by 1/3 after 1 km. When I don't have this high range after charging, I arrive on destination with more range then at the start. Planning a trip is very difficult, I have no idea how far I'll get. Even after 6 months of use every day is different in range (on the same roads in similar conditions). I wonder if some of you have the same experience and what was done about it? Is there a battery or engine-problem or is the Nyon itself the problem?

Comment: This is relatively common for many gauges -- if you drive a car, the distance to empty meter will change sometimes weirdly to increase/decrease mileage based on driving habits or other things. And the battery capacity will decrease as the battery is repeatedly used in this case. You're best off finding a forum of users of this bike and asking them this.

Comment: Yeah, it's difficult to estimate the range of an electric bike using a relatively "dumb" meter since it depends on both riding conditions and the charge state of the battery.  Riding conditions of course cannot be easily predicted, and, with modern NiMH or Li-Ion batteries there is no way to simply measure battery voltage/current and determine it's charge state -- a device must be employed which "memorizes" the historical charge/discharge pattern and analyzes that.

Comment: This is the definition of range anxiety.  It applies to all electric vehicles, but electric cars tend to have no second motor.  You are the second motor on the bike.

There may be a new firmware for your bike, it may be user-upgradeable or it may be a dealer service.   Otherwise you just have to learn to read your instruments and interpret their output.  Reading the remaining energy in a battery is hard, because mere voltage doesn't show it.  Complex/expensive Battery Management Systems learn over time and adjust.  You'll have to do that on your wetware.

Comment: By "wetware" Criggie means "in your head".